# Enable/Disable a form while in an another form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to figure out how to disable my form(Form1.vb) without hiding it then enabling it after I'm done with the other form(Form2.vb).

I've searched on youtube but it says C#. I've tried it but somehow it was indicated as an error in VS 2015. I tried messing around with the syntax because I really can't figure it out. The syntax that I have tried is "LandingForm.ActiveForm.Owner.Enabled = True".

Indicated below are the codes of my system. The first one is form1.vb/LandingForm.vb and the second one is form2.vb/AcctSettings.vb.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Enabled = False
        AcctSettings.Show()
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        LandingForm.ActiveForm.Owner.Enabled = True
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

Am I missing something? Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you tried `AcctSettings.ShowDialog` ? It will have the desired effect without any side-effects of losing the displayed form if the user starts switching between applications or just randomly clicking around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your form1 just have a simple line like

```
Form2.Show()
```

wherever/however you wish to open the other form (button etc.)

then in the code for that form2 in the formload handeler have

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

     Form1.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

This will keep form1 open but basically grey it out.
Then have a simple button click like so to have access to form 1.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Form1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

And you are done! And if you wish just add another button or a IF statement to the button2 sub and say `form1.enabled = false` if you want to be able to enable/disable etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made too complicated. I never knew it was that simple. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yep! Can be done fairly simple! Obviously many ways to do it probably and perhaps better and more "proper" ways to do so but this is just a simple way to do what you wish!

Comment: @JayveeBiares let us know if it works and if so don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. My bad. I'm new in Stack Overflow. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To **enable/disable** your userform : 
To disable your userform you will need yo enable it before :

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

     Form1.Enabled = True
     Form1.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

To disable it will be easier you just got to set your `userform.enabled` as False

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Form2.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

If you want to **close** your userform `useroform.Unload` might be the solution.

In your code it would be like this :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Enabled = False
        AcctSettings.Show()
        form1.Unload
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        LandingForm.ActiveForm.Owner.Enabled = True
        Me.Hide()
        form2.Unload
End Sub
```

an other option is to **Hide** your user form : it will just hide the userform and will not release the objects and variables from the memory. Where as Unload method will release the objects and variables from the memory.

```
UserForm1.Hide
```

To **conclude** : **Hide** method will be used when we want to hide the form temorarly and to show after sometime to the user. Where as **unload** will be used when it completes the task.

**Note** that this is **YourUserForm_Name**.Unload

Comment: My Visual Studio 2015 is not familiar with unload? I don't know. However, I tried close. Does it count as unload? Or are they different?

Comment: @JayveeBiares  It's to do with the sequence in which all of the events fire as a form closes.
For a form the event process is:
**Unload > Deactivate > Close**
Also you can **cancel an unload** in code (you can use it to check that all of the fields in a form have been filled in correctly etc.) whereas you **cannot cancel a close**